# Discord py forward messages(with embeds) sent on one channel to another and how to determine number of members in a server?

Tags: python, discord, embed, discord.py, forward

I want to forward messages sent on a particular channel to another channel based on number of reactions on  emoji reaction. The message has a few embeds and is being sent by the YAGPDB.xyz bot from a sub reddit. If the message in a particular channel gets more than one down vote reaction I want to forward that message to another channel and delete it on the current channel. Here's what a typical message from this bot looks like(with embeds),

[image]
I have written the following code,

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id in CHANNEL_LIST:
        if payload.emoji.name=='\U0001F53C':
            channel=client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message=await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            reaction=get(message.reactions,emoji=payload.emoji.name)
            if reaction and reaction.count>1:
                await message.pin()
        elif payload.emoji.name=='\U0001F53B':
            channel=client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message=await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            reaction=get(message.reactions,emoji=payload.emoji.name)
            if reaction and reaction.count>1:
                channel=client.get_channel(DELETED_MESSAGES_CHANNEL)
                await channel.send('{}: {}'.format(message.author, message.content),embed=message.content.embeds)
                await message.delete()
```

I get the following error,

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "s.py", line 46, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await channel.send('{}: {}'.format(message.author, message.content),embed=message.content.embeds)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'embeds'
```

If I use `embed=message.embeds` instead of `message.content.embeds`, i get the following error,

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "s.py", line 46, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await channel.send('{}: {}'.format(message.author, message.content),embed=message.embeds)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 828, in send
    embed = embed.to_dict()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

How do I get all the embeds in this message and forward it as it was sent here to another channel? And also, how do I get to know the number of members in my server who are **NOT BOTS**?  Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using just `embed=message.embeds`? Pretty sure that `embeds` is at the same level as `content`, not a subordinate.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Yes I have tried that and have edited the question to include it's output in the ending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await channel.send('{}: {}'.format(message.author,message.content),embed=message.embeds[0])` Typically, there is only one embed in the embeds list object. So, in most cases just use embeds[0]. I haven't seen messages with multiple embeds so far.